# Could 'the' suggest a patronizing tone?

Tags: definite-article, politeness

In [this blog](https://www.verbling.com/articles/post/how-to-use-articles-in-english-advanced-#:%7E:text=them%20sound%20important.-,Example%203.,as%20%27Protect%20the%20Tiger%27%2C%20%27Protect%20the%20Panda%27%20etc.,-Articles%20are%20one), the writer says as follows.

> Example 3.
>
> a. ✓ Asians usually have dark hair.
>
> b. ☓ **The** Asian usually has dark hair.
>
> You should never use this construction to talk about groups of people, as it can sound racist. People should be treated as individuals, never conceptualised.
>
> Example 4.
>
> The charity 'Amnesty International' makes clever use of this construction in their slogan:
>
> Protect **the** Human
>
> By using 'the human' instead of 'humans' Amnesty International draws attention to the fact that people are vulnerable living creatures. 'Protect the Human' reminds us of slogans such as 'Protect the Tiger', 'Protect the Panda' etc.

Why does using 'the human' instead of 'humans' draw attention to the fact that people are vulnerable, living creatures? Is it because *conceptualisations* (this term is taken from Example 3) using 'the' suggest a patronizing tone? If it is, then Example 3 makes more sense.

Comment: *Why does using 'the human' instead of 'humans' can draw attention to the fact that people are vulnerable living creatures?* <-- The last sentence of the text you quoted directly answers this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blog post is discussing a specific construction, where "the" is combined with a singular noun to refer to it as a *kind* rather than a particular instance. It is a common way to refer to a kind of creature ("the mountain lion is native to North America"). It is not necessarily patronizing if used in this way, but using this construction to talk about kinds of people could give the impression that they are being disrespectfully categorized like animals.

There is a separate construction where "the" is combined with a *plural* noun referring to a category of people—"the Asians", "the Jews", etc. With demographic categories, this can come across as disrespectful because it signals distancing (emphasizes that the speaker is separate from that group).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know 'the old' is impolite. Your answer reminds me of the first episode of *Inside Job* where Reagan's dad call rich people 'the rich'.

Comment: What about the movie name 'the Good, the Bad and the Ugly'?

Comment: That's yet another construction where an *adjective* denoting a personal characteristic can follow "the" to make a referring expression. This construction is not necessarily impolite (though "old" is sometimes softened to "older people", "the elderly", etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The plural form is a generalization that refers to an identifiable group as a whole.
Its use can be perfectly acceptable ("*Men are taller than women.*"), or offensive ("*[nationality]s are of low intelligence.*").
The observation can be true or false, but it always applies to the typical or average member of the group, and not necessarily to every member.
"*Men are taller than women.*" does not imply that "All *men are taller than* all *women*.".

The singular form is far more specific. It is not referring to a characteristic of an average member of the group; it is referring to any randomly chosen individual from that group.
Unless the characteristic is overwhelmingly true (e.g. "*The lion is much larger than the house cat.*"), it is a form of bigotry and stereotyping.

Unless one is talking about two specific individuals, saying "*The woman is smaller and weaker than the man.*" is equivalent to saying "All *women are smaller and weaker than* all *men.*".
Such a belief can be used to justify hiring a short skinny man for a job rather than a much better qualified tall muscular woman.
She would not even have been given an interview because by being female she is inherently unsuited for the position.

On the other hand, "*Protect the human.*" does imply "*Protect* all *humans.*".
But that *is* the message that it is meant to convey.
It is not inherently offensive (except possibly to non-humans).

Answer (score 0):

This particular use of the definite article *can* be offensive when it is used to make *generalisations* about certain groups of people, such as a particular ethnic group or gender. Your example of "the Asian" certainly falls into this category.

For example (and please forgive the example, ladies), saying "*the woman is happiest in the kitchen*" is basically the same as saying "*women are happiest in the kitchen*". "*The woman*" in statements like this represents all women or a 'typical' woman. Statements like this are offensive because they make the assumption that this is true of *all* women everywhere. They are especially offensive when they imply negative traits, question intelligence or assign demeaning roles to people.

Of course, it isn't the definite article that makes something offensive, just the sentiment behind it. "Save the tiger" is not at all offensive, nor "ban the bomb".

Another answer suggested that "help the aged" would be offensive. That was the name of a charity in the UK for a very long time. But if someone found that offensive, it is for a very different reason. There is no generalisation being made, not even a suggestion that all aged need help. It is simply that some people don't like being called "old", "elderly" or "aged".

Comment: Not only do you not answer the question, but your first sentence is wrong. Using, for example, "The" + singular-form race, at this point in history, is in many cases to be avoided altogether (not just in generalizations). Indeed, and contrary to your point, the form [article]+[racial adjective without a noun after] will likely be taken with offense when it is used out of place, regardless of sentiment. This is an important point for learners to understand, particularly in the U.S.

Comment: @cruthers No, you're entirely wrong again. Such usage requires context, and I explain which context is considered offensive. Google "The American" and you'll find countless socially acceptable uses.

Comment: I'm obviously not talking about "the American." You don't come close to covering when and where it's offensive. If I were you, I would just delete this answer.

Comment: @cruthers If you think that it's okay to say "the American" but not the same for other races then that is the most blatantly racist thing I've seen on this site.

Comment: @Astralbee American is not a race. In the context of nationalities, "the [nationality]" isn't inherently an offensive construction. Where the term refers to race and religion, it very often is an offensive construction.

Comment: @katy Racist, nationalist, both are the same, really - a belief that one people is superior to another because of their heritage. Trying to pigeonhole different types of bigotry is a known smokescreen tactic of bigots.

Comment: @Astralbee Identifying someone by nationality is not the same as nationalism. You are being deliberately disingenuous.

Comment: ​“The guy who made my sandwich was a/an/the American/Brit” vs. “the guy who made my sandwich was a/an/the [single racial adjective].” If you think those are the same, you should come visit​ any large city in the U.S​.​ and talk like that.​ I’d like to see how long you last.

Comment: @katy no *you* are being disingenuous because you know that is not what I said. You argued that a 'racist' phrase cannot be racist if it uses a nationality and not a race. I essentially said that it would just be nationalism. I equated racism to nationalism.

Comment: @cruthers As a British person, I find the term 'Brit' offensive, especially when said by persons of other nationalities. The correct term is 'Briton'.

Comment: Ah, so we agree. "The Briton made my sandwich" would be acceptable, whereas "the [racial adj]" would not.

Comment: @cruthers No, I was just pointing out your use of a racist term.

Comment: @Astralbee, you are turning into what you despise.

Answer (score -1):

A slogan like "Protect the panda", as referenced in your book, suggests that the existence of the panda as a type of animal is threatened in some way. For a contrasting example, if "Protect dogs" were a slogan, it would probably be interpreted as a call for people to be concerned with the safety or welfare of dogs, not a call for preserving the existence of all dogs (or any particular breed of dog, for that matter). "Protect *the* dog" (in the context of slogans) would suggest that the preservation of dogs as an existing type of animal is the goal - so it would be quite surprising to hear this particular slogan, as, to my knowledge, the dog is thriving as an animal and is under no particular threat of extinction.

"Protect the Human," you'll see, follows a parallel construction, and reads as if "the human" is threatened as a species. I don't necessarily agree that, as the book puts it, this construction "draws attention to the fact that people are vulnerable living creatures," but that's for the reader to decide. The immediate effect is to call to mind the human as a species in the same way a species of animal would be called to mind, and I think that's really the point of the example.

So, as far as the use of "the" being offensive or patronizing in other contexts (similar to Ex. 3) - that isn't in play here.